# How to generate PEM encoded Certificate Request File

Tags: key, payment-gateway, csr

Actually I want to Masterpass payment gateway to my a wordpress website when I am doing the I am using [this website](https://developer.mastercard.com/portal/display/api/MasterPass+-+Merchant+Checkout) 
This gives the following massage for CSR file
[image]

I have not installed IIS on my system I'm using wamp server.

I don't know how to generate this CSR file can anybody help me complete this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the tool Mastercard provide, then the biggest problem is figuring out that almost everybody refers to a certificate request file as a CSR and using that as a search term turns up lots of HOWTOs.

I use [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) as it is ubiquitous and free.

```
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.csr
```

Comment: I'd use OpenSSL on Windows too.